# User account activation links are lacking query strings

Tags: login, user-registration, email-verification

This is probably a longshot but I'm out of ideas.

When a user registers on my WordPress site (using WordPress core registration form) it sends an email with the standard "...to set your password, visit the following address..." message. However, with my custom theme there are no query strings at the end of the link, so it just goes to example.com/wp-login.php

I disabled my theme and registered another user and that email **did** have the necessary query strings.

While I was glad to see it worked, I'm now completely stumped as to why my theme is stripping them off.

I do have some custom security functions, but the only thing that targets the login page is after a user triggers an invalid login attempt using the `login_errors` hook.

I also have the WordFence plugin active, but it was also active when I changed themes and had success.

I hope this question isn't too vague. I'm just looking for troubleshooting steps for this

Comment: Do you happen to have a function called `wp_new_user_notification` in your custom theme?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just searched the parent theme, child theme, and all plugins and nothing uses that function.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was setting the default mime type for `wp_mail_content_type` to be `text/html` which [according to the notes on the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type#Notes) can cause [this particular issue](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21095).

I've removed the code from my functions file, and the registration email looks better, but (and I haven't seen WordPress's emails in a long time) still doesn't look 100% normal... I need to find another self-hosted WordPress site that allows registration to compare, but is the activation email supposed to look like this?

[image]

It's odd to me that there are two links in the email- one with the proper query strings, and another without. Just doesn't seem that user-friendly- is that correct?

Anyway, if anyone else runs into this same issue- the current solution for me was to entirely remove the custom `wp_mail_content_type` function that changes the default MIME type for WordPress email to be HTML.